# R - How to fill in values in NA, but only when ending value is the same as the beginning value?

Tags: r, na, fill

I have the following example data:

Example <- data.frame(col1 =c(1, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, 6, 8, NA, 2, NA))

| col1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| NA |
| NA |
| 4 |
| NA |
| NA |
| 6 |
| NA |
| NA |
| NA |
| 6 |
| 8 |
| NA |
| 2 |
| NA |

I want to fill the NAs with value from above, but only if the NAs are between 2 identical values. In this example the first NA gap from 1 to 4 should not be filled with 1s. But the gap between the first 6 and the second 6 should be filled, with 6s. All other values should stay NA.
Therefore, afterwards it should look like:

| col1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| NA |
| NA |
| 4 |
| NA |
| NA |
| 6 |
| 6 |
| 6 |
| 6 |
| 6 |
| 8 |
| NA |
| 2 |
| NA |

But in reality I do not have only 15 observations, but over 50000. Therefore I need a efficient solution, which is more difficult than I thought. I tried to use the Fill function but was not able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `zoo` option could be:

```
df %>%
    mutate(cond = na.locf0(col1) == na.locf0(col1, fromLast = TRUE),
           col1 = ifelse(cond, na.locf0(col1), col1)) %>%
    select(-cond)

   col1
1     1
2    NA
3    NA
4     4
5    NA
6    NA
7     6
8     6
9     6
10    6
11    6
12    8
13   NA
14    2
15   NA
```

Comment: Your zoo solution works fine. But with dplyr it does not work, well it does in the example, but not in my real data.  Seems as the NAs get filled after the begining and ending value, where it should really end. Like if the data would be: (6, NA, NA, 6, NA, 8) your dplyr solution would give out: (6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8). But again, the zoo solution works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dply solution:

First I create the data in tibble format:

```
df <- tibble(
  x = c(1, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        4, NA_real_, NA_real_,
        6, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        6, 8, NA_real_, 2, NA_real_)
)
```

Next, I create two grouping variables which will be helpful in identifying the first and the last non-NA value.
I then save these reference values to `ref_start` and `ref_end`.
In the end I overwrite the values of `x`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(gr1 = cumsum(!is.na(x))) %>%
  group_by(gr1) %>%
  mutate(ref_start = first(x)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(gr2 = lag(gr1, default = 1)) %>%
  group_by(gr2) %>%
  mutate(ref_end = last(x)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(x = if_else(is.na(x) & ref_start == ref_end, ref_start, x))

# A tibble: 15 x 1
       x
   <dbl>
 1     1
 2    NA
 3    NA
 4     4
 5    NA
 6    NA
 7     6
 8     6
 9     6
10     6
11     6
12     8
13    NA
14     2
15    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- data.frame(col1 =c(1, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, 6, 8, NA, 2, NA))

library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

setDT(df)[!is.na(col1), n := .N, by = col1] %>% 
  .[, n := nafill(n, type = "locf")] %>% 
  .[n == 2, col1 := nafill(col1, type = "locf")] %>% 
  .[, n := NULL] %>% 
  .[]
#>     col1
#>  1:    1
#>  2:   NA
#>  3:   NA
#>  4:    4
#>  5:   NA
#>  6:   NA
#>  7:    6
#>  8:    6
#>  9:    6
#> 10:    6
#> 11:    6
#> 12:    8
#> 13:   NA
#> 14:    2
#> 15:   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:
Logic:

1. Create an `id` column
2. Remove all na rows
3. Flag if next value is the same
4. `right_join` with first `Example` df
5. `fill` down `flag` and corresponding `col1.y`
6. `mutate` with an `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Example <- Example %>% 
  mutate(id=row_number())

Example %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  mutate(flag = ifelse(col1==lead(col1), TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  right_join(Example, by="id") %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  fill(col1.y, .direction="down") %>% 
  fill(flag, .direction="down") %>% 
  mutate(col1.x = ifelse(flag==TRUE, col1.y, col1.x), .keep="unused") %>% 
  select(col1 = col1.x)
```

Output:

```
   col1
1     1
2    NA
3    NA
4     4
5    NA
6    NA
7     6
8     6
9     6
10    6
11    6
12    8
13   NA
14    2
15   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution above with data.table (from Yuriy Saraykin) works only for the example. As Daniel Hendrick comments : Seems as the NAs get filled after the begining and ending value, where it should really end. Like if the data would be: (6, NA, NA, 6, NA, 8) your dplyr solution would give out: (6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8).

Here is an another proposition with data.table:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(col1 =c(1, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, 8, NA, 2, NA))

cond = nafill(df$col1, type = "locf") == nafill(df$col1, type = "nocb")
df[which(cond==T), col1 := nafill(df$col1, type = "locf")[which(cond==T)]]
df$col1
[1]  1 NA NA  4 NA NA  6  6  6  6  6 NA NA  8 NA  2 NA
```